# Apply style to hyperlink

Tags: vba, ms-office, ms-word

Is there a way to apply style to hyperlink, without selecting it?

For example, this works:

```
Sub ChangeStyle()
    Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Fields(1).Result.Select
    Selection.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHyperlinkFollowed
End Sub
```

But I don't like the gray selection area:

[image]

Here is what I try to accomplish:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Sub ChangeStyle()
    Selection.Range.Hyperlinks(1).Range.Fields(1).Result.Style = Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHyperlinkFollowed
End Sub
```